# Get the latest rows where like

Tags: mysql, group-by

i am trying to get the latest record who has the specified "pull" value, and then group by imei number. But i am getting the wrong output, the time does not match with does i have in my databse

This is my tabel.

```
    IMEI              TIME                      STATUS
    354851057191551   2013-06-25 10:11:30       pull getrestbyimei
    354851057191551   2013-06-25 10:10:36       Push getrestbyimei
    354851057234971   2013-06-25 10:10:34       Push getbookings
    351895053436612   2013-06-25 10:10:32       pull getrestbyimei
    351895053436612   2013-06-25 10:10:31       pull getrestbyimei
```

Desired output:

```
        IMEI              TIME                      STATUS
        354851057191551   2013-06-25 10:11:30       pull getrestbyimei
        351895053436612   2013-06-25 10:10:32       pull getrestbyimei
```

This is how i tried:

```
SELECT imei as IMEI, MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) as TIME, action as STATUS
    FROM testlog
    where action like  'pull%'
    GROUP BY imei
order by TIME asc
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do `order by TIME desc` to retrieve the latest record

Comment: But that is only for one row?

Comment: you said `Get the latest record where like`

Comment: Arrh, sorry, i meant multiple rows, not only one

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function.

```
SELECT imei as IMEI, MAX(timestamp) as TIME, action as STATUS
    FROM testlog
    where action like  'pull%'
    GROUP BY imei
order by TIME asc
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f766/2).

Answer (score 1):

You need a subselect to get the latest records timestamp of each type and then  join that back against the table to get the rest of the rows columns. Otherwise the action you get may or may not be the latest action (if you have multiple actions which are different but start with pull).

```
SELECT a.imei, a.timestamp, a.action
FROM testlog a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT imei as IMEI, MAX(timestamp) as MaxTime
    FROM testlog
    where action like  'pull%'
    GROUP BY imei
) b
ON a.imei = b.imei
AND a.timestamp = b.MaxTime
```

The other issue is that your timestamp is a timestamp, not a unix timestamp. So you should not convert it from a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can user ORDER BY PRIMARY_KEY DESC

here PRIMARY_KEY is your primary key field

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT imei as IMEI, MAX(timestamp) as TIME, action as STATUS
   FROM testlog
   where action like  'pull%'
   GROUP BY imei
   order by TIME asc
```